# Cronjob PHP script output not executin desire script

Tags: php, email

I want to execute a php script in order to send an email. I've added the path to file in cpanel cronjob but when the email is sent i receive

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.43
Content-type: text/html

In cpanel at cronjob i've place the following code:

```
php /home/themesby/public_html/reminder/trimite-email.php
```

The code that i want to execute is below:

```
<?php
include('db-connect.php');
$number_of_days_before = 1;
$email = "adriann.mihai@gmail.com";
$reminder_details = "";
$todays_date = date("Ymd");
$year = substr($todays_date, 0, 4);
$month = substr($todays_date, 4, 2);
$date = substr($todays_date, 6, 2);
$trigger_date = date("Ymd", mktime (0,0,0,$month,$date-$number_of_days_before,$year));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM evenimente WHERE data_eveniment <=$trigger_date ORDER BY data_eveniment ASC");
$nr = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$year = substr($row["data_eveniment"], 0, 4);
$month = substr($row["data_eveniment"], 4, 2);
$date = substr($row["data_eveniment"], 6, 2);
$data_eveniment = date("M j, Y", mktime (0,0,0,$month,$date,$year));
$reminder_details .= "Eveniment: ".$row["nume_eveniment"]."\n";
$reminder_details .= "Data: ".$data_eveniment."\n";
$reminder_details .= $row["descriere_eveniment"]."\n\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
if(!empty($nr))
{
$mailheader = "From: Planificator <$email>\nX-Mailer: Reamintire\nContent-Type: text/plain";
mail("$email","Reamintire","$reminder_details","$mailheader");
// Delete the sent reminders
mysql_query("DELETE FROM evenimente WHERE data_eveniment <= $trigger_date");
}
?>
```

What might be the source of the problem? Thx in advance.

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: your script is at risk, you should avoid utilizing mysql_

Comment: Does the script work when you call it directly, without the crond?

Comment: What is the exact problem? And that is a lot of nasty date manipulations that you can avoid by using a normal date type in your database. And if the `data_eveniment` is a varchar instead of an integer, you need to quote your variable.

Comment: I didn't tried that! I'll try using mysqli

Comment: @ameenulla0007 How is the script at risk?

Comment: use of mysql_ is not recommended as it is deprecated, and its not suppose to be secure there on.

Comment: @ameenulla0007 It's deprecated and has been removed from php 7 but it is non unsafe by itself. And the sql in the question has no security problem. Well, apart from the fact that it could be used to spam the OP's mailbox :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include an absolute path to your php binary like this:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/themesby/public_html/reminder/trimite-email.php
```

Comment: Yeah, same problem...:(

Comment: maybe your script needs to exucutable  by issuing chnod +x  /home/themesby/public_html/reminder/trimite-email.php